# In URL API version routing in PHP

Tags: php, rest, url-routing

I am thinking of a good way of routing requests in a RESTful API which has versions in the URL, for example

```
api.example.com/v2/resource
api.example.com/v3/resource
```

In particular, how to map these major versions in the URL to the application layout? Something that looks like this?

```
application/v2/models
application/v2/controllers
....
application/v3/models
application/v3/controllers
.....
```

The closest PHP implementation of this that I know about is using modules in Zend Framework 1.x where the structure would look like this

```
application/modules/v2/models
application/modules/v2/controllers
....
application/modules/v3/models
application/modules/v3/controllers
.....
```

But these versions aren't really modules so this feels a bit wrong. I am wondering if there are better ideas out there?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the API version from the URL and rather use HTTP `Accept` headers, e.g.

```
HTTP/1.0 GET /resource
Accept: application/vnd.foo.bar.v1+json
```

Clients that support version 2 of your API would use:

```
HTTP/1.0 GET /resource
Accept: application/vnd.foo.bar.v2+json
```

See [Designing HTTP Interfaces and RESTful Web Services](http://www.slideshare.net/Wombert/designing-http-interfaces-and-restful-web-services-dpc2012-20120608) for more ideas about REST API design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already done some research on the best way to version the API and including them in the URL is the most appropriate for what I am working on (some clients are not able to manipulate the HTTP headers, for example). And to be honest my question is about the application layout rather than how to accept versions from the clients, even if I switch to using HTTP Accept headers I still need to layout my application to handle the multiple versions?

Comment: `some clients are not able to manipulate the HTTP headers` - every single HTTP client library I know of is able to manipulate the headers.

Comment: VoiceXML browsers allow you to make HTTP requests but they won't let you manipulate the headers, at least it is not in the standard. However, again, this doesn't answer my question about application layout?